# Rails 5: could not convert "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" to nil Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, assets

I have problem when applying vendors assets on rails 5.0.0.1 on ruby 2.3.1.

I am getting this errors:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (could not convert "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" to nil):
4:     <title>Inventory</title>
5:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
6: 
7:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
8:     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
9: 
10:   </head>
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1205425238055745241_70060113419160'
  Rendering /home/jerry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@inventory/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /home/jerry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@inventory/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /home/jerry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@inventory/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (3.1ms)
  Rendering /home/jerry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@inventory/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /home/jerry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@inventory/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendering /home/jerry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@inventory/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /home/jerry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@inventory/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /home/jerry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@inventory/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (15.9ms)
```

I have add folder fonts on assets folder and add that to `application.rb`
I have searched on google with no luck.

What I did wrong, please?

Comment: first, find out what asset is causing the error. try and remove the fonts one by one till you get to `the one` might be a broken file or something with the permissions

Comment: yeah I have, apparently there is one broken file, thanks.